# How do you sort on more than 3 criteria in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

It looks like you can only choose 3 criteria from Data -> Sort. Is there a way (potentially programmatic) to use additional criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, without adjusting the code it is not possible to do that. In theory it should be quite easy to adjust this and remove this limitation. For the 3-5 release a voluteer did something similar already for conditional formatting.

The code is in http://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/core/sc/inc/sortparam.hxx but it is not just done with increasing MAXSORT. There needs to be a according change in the ui too and ideally switching to a std::vector or another dynamic datastructure. This is an easy task and I just created https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45747 for this. So if you wanna join in Libreoffice development you can easily do this.